# Accessing a specific value in an Array in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, struct

I've been developing a project in C for an implementation of the African board game Oware, and am strugling with the capture feature, because the pit where the seeds are taken from isn't being emptied like it should. My implementation for this reads as follows

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define num_players 2
#define num_pits_player 6
#define num_seeds 4

struct gameState{
    int pits[num_players][num_pits_player]; //pits for the seeds
    int deposit[num_players]; //deposit for the pits
    int playerTurn; //keeping track of whose turn it is
};

void displayGame(struct gameState *game){
    printf("\n");
    printf("|--------|--|--player1--|--|--------|\n"
           "|score_p1|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|score_p0|\n"
           "|  %2d    |-----------------|   %2d   |\n"
           "|        |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|        |\n"
           "|--------|--|--player0--|--|--------|\n",
           game->pits[1][0], game->pits[1][1], game->pits[1][2], game->pits[1][3], game->pits[1][4], game->pits[1][5],
           game->deposit[1], game->deposit[0],
           game->pits[0][0], game->pits[0][1], game->pits[0][2], game->pits[0][3], game->pits[0][4], game->pits[0][5]);
}
void capture(struct gameState *game, int player, int pitToSow){
    int currentPit = (pitToSow + 1) % num_pits_player; //variable for the current pit
    int seedsInCurrentPit = game->pits[(player + currentPit / num_pits_player) % num_players][currentPit % num_pits_player]; //getting the seeds in the current pit
    int opponent = (player + 1) % num_players;

    if(seedsInCurrentPit == 2 || seedsInCurrentPit == 3) { //checking for conditions to sow
        game->deposit[player] += seedsInCurrentPit; //adding to deposit
        game->pits[opponent][seedsInCurrentPit] = 0; //dont work
        printf("player %d sowed %d seeds from \nplayer %d's pit number %d", player, seedsInCurrentPit, opponent, game->pits[opponent][seedsInCurrentPit]);
        //check suplementary rules
    }
}

void makeMove(struct gameState *game){
    int player = game->playerTurn;
    printf("Player %d's turn.\nPick a pit to sow(1-6): ", player);
    int pitToSow;
    if(scanf("%d", &pitToSow) != 1 || pitToSow < 1 || pitToSow > 6) { //validating if the pit is valid
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    pitToSow--; // adjusting for zero-based indexing

    // Get the seeds from the selected pit
    int seedsToSow = game->pits[player][pitToSow];
    int lastPitSown = -1; // Initialize the variable to track the last pit sown
    int lastPlayer = player; // Initialize the variable to track the player of the last pit sown
    //zero out the pit
    game->pits[player][pitToSow] = 0;
    for(int currentPit = pitToSow + 1; seedsToSow > 0; currentPit++, seedsToSow--) {
        // Distribute one seed to the current pit - moving mechanic
        game->pits[(player + currentPit / num_pits_player) % num_players][currentPit % num_pits_player]++;
        lastPitSown = currentPit % num_pits_player; // Update the last pit sown
        lastPlayer = (player + currentPit / num_pits_player) % num_players; // Update the player of the last pit sown
    }

    if(lastPitSown >= 0 && lastPitSown < num_pits_player){ //if the last pit sown is in the scope of the array
        capture(game, player, pitToSow); //call capture function
    }

    //update turns
    game->playerTurn = (game->playerTurn + 1) % num_players;
}
void startGame(struct gameState *game){
    for(int player=0; player < num_players; player++){ //rotating the players
        for(int pit=0; pit < num_pits_player; pit++){ //populating each player's pits
            game->pits[player][pit] = num_seeds;
        }
        game->deposit[player] = 0; //init of deposits/score
    }
    game->playerTurn=0;
}

int main() {
    struct gameState game;
    //picking the game mode to play

    //game start - populate each pit w/ 4, deposit w/ 0
    startGame(&game);
    //display game
    displayGame(&game);
    while(game.deposit[0] <= 25 || game.deposit[1] <= 25){
        makeMove(&game);
        displayGame(&game);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried using `game->pits[opponent][seedsInCurrentPit] = 0;` but even though I believe the indexes to be right, the code does not run as expected. I have also added `printf("player %d sowed %d seeds from \nplayer %d's pit number %d", player, seedsInCurrentPit, opponent, game->pits[opponent][seedsInCurrentPit]);` as a debug statement that seems to return just fine, however the value that I'd need to zero out (the pit that holds seedsInCurrentPit) does not.
Lastly, I've tried using `game->pits[(player + currentPit / num_pits_player) % num_players][currentPit % num_pits_player] = 0;` but to no avail.

An example for the return I get when I run my current code implementation is
[image: Test run example]

As can be seen, the debug statement returns just fine, as the pit to be emptied should be the first of `player 1`(pit 0), and the correct number of seeds gets added to `player 0's deposit`, however the pit where the seeds are taken from isn't emptied as it should, and behaves like a normal pit.
For this scenario, I've fed the following input:
player 0: 3
player 1: 1
player 0: 4
player 1: 3
player 0: 2
Right here, capture happens

Furthermore, I've noticed that player 1 does not capture any seeds from player 0, even if conditions are met, as shown in the image below
[image: Player 1 error in capture]

This should have prompted the capture of 2 seeds for player 1, but it did not.

Comment: Please revise the above to clarify what the question is that you want answered.  It's good you have tried stuff but your journey is secondary.  A particular powerful way is to hard-code a failing test case in `main()`.  I have this state then then when I run capture I get X but expect Y.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have edited the post to hopefully clarify its objective.

Comment: Just a remark: Should it not be deposit1 <= 25 **&&** deposit2 <= 25?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica the win condition is if one of the player has 25 or more seeds in their deposit, therefore it is deposit[0] <= 25 **||** deposit[0] <= 25, correct?

Comment: Well, the loop would not terminate if one deposit is above 25 but the other one isn't (the *or* makes the condition still true). I think that is not what you want.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica but doesn't using **&&** make it so that the loop only terminate o both are 25 and above?

Comment: @ramwen0 `while (a && b)` runs the loop as long as both conditions are true, in this case: both deposits have fewer than 25 beans. The end condition is that *one of them* has more; then the loop should terminate, which it does only with &&. In your code, it is enough if just one player has fewer than 25, even though the other one may have more beans; that way, the game continues even though one player has won a long time ago.

Comment: These two lines in a row suggest a logic error: `int currentPit = (pitToSow + 1) % num_pits_player;`     `int seedsInCurrentPit = game->pits[(player + currentPit / num_pits_player)` (...)  -- The first line always sets `currentPit` to be less than `num_pits_player`, so in the second line `currentPit / num_pits_player` is always zero ; so why do you have a calculation that is always zero?

Comment: We greatly prefer text to images of textual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in several comments, you seem to be confusing the effect of boolean AND and OR. (My favourite blind spot is mixing up the effects of integer division (`a/b`) and modulo (`a%b`). I know what I want, but my fingers type the *other* operator.) Review is recommended.

---

Having long ago seen a reference to this game, your code was intriguing. However, the implementation struck me as a morass of *difficult-to-discern* operations involving *too many* variables each with names that were *far too long*. C is not COBOL, and this application has no need for long variable names. (When the purpose and scope is restricted, I recommend choosing brevity over verbosity.)

Below is a distillation of your original code. Noteworthy attributes:

1. The internal representation can be whatever best serves the purpose. A single array (of 12 *pits*) simplifies modulo wrapping as seeds are distributed.
2. Factoring code into functions is commendable, but can sometimes obscure operations, rather than helping the reader understand.
3. Comments should only explain the unusual, not the obvious (to a reader conversant with the language.)
4. Below uses single byte `unsigned char` for the number of *seeds* and the scores (data range is `0` to `48`). This allows `memset()` (library function) to initialise the number of seeds in each *pit*.
5. Having read the Wikipedia page for this game, the code below seems to fully implement the scoring (correctly, I hope.) It is possible to collect points from several of one's opponent's pits in a single ply.
6. The game is played *counter-clockwise*.

The user feedback in your code - `printf()` - gives the impression that much time was spent to achieve a particular layout. Below is slightly *trimmed* from that version.

Recommend focussing first on getting the program logic to work as needed. There is much wisdom in the adages, "*The proof is in the pudding,*" and "*Appearances can be deceiving.*"

For educational purposes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define nPlayer 2
#define nOne 6
#define nPit (2 * nOne)
#define nSeed 4

typedef unsigned char t_Pit;

void show( t_Pit p[], t_Pit s[] ) {
    printf(
        "\n"
        "------+-----player1-----+------\n"
        "      |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n"
        "P1 %2d +-----------------+ P0 %2d\n"
        "      |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n"
        "------+-----player0-----+------\t\t",
        p[ 5], p[ 4], p[ 3], p[ 2], p[ 1], p[ 0], // NB: custom indexing
        s[ 1], s[ 0],
        p[ 6], p[ 7], p[ 8], p[ 9], p[10], p[11] ); // note indexing
}

int main( void ) {
    t_Pit   pit[ nPit ] = { 0 },
            score[ nPlayer ] = { 0 };

    memset( pit, nSeed, sizeof pit );
    show( pit, score );

    /* note the use of the && operator here */
//  for( int player = 0; score[0] <= 25 && score[1] <= 25; player = !player ) { // wrong!
    for( int player = 0; score[0] < 25 && score[1] < 25; player = !player ) {
        printf( "%d selects pit (1-6): ", player );

        int from, to;
        if( scanf( "%d", &from ) != 1 || from < 1 || from > 6 ) {
            puts( "scanf failed" );
            return 1;
        }
        from -= 1; // 0 indexing

        if( player == 0 ) // change to "high range" of pits?
            from += nOne;
        to = from; // for now...

        int nSow = pit[ from ];
        pit[ from ] = 0;

        while( nSow-- )
            pit[ to = (to+1)%nPit ]++;

        // test = false when stepping out of opponents range of pits
        for( ; to/nOne != from/nOne; to = (to+(nPit-1))%nPit ) // modulo -1
            if( pit[ to ] == 2 || pit[ to ] == 3 ) {
                score[ player ] += pit[ to ];
                pit[ to ] = 0;
            } else break;

        show( pit, score );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
Swept up in the modifications to the OP code, I didn't stop to realise that the major loop conditional is wrong! Doh!

It should be `score[0] < 25 && score[1] < 25`

According to Wikipedia, a `draw` is possible. When one player gains 25+ *seeds*, that player has **won** the game.

---

**Revision:**
It's a tricky game to play solo because the board orientation is "fixed". Thinking left-to-right for some moves, then right-to-left for others. Slows down testing when mistakes are made.

Below is roughly the same code modified so that the current player sees the board "left-to-right" from their perspective. This revision is to demonstrate the flexibility of extending *compact* code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char t_Pit;

void show( int player, t_Pit p[], t_Pit s[], int win ) {
    int a = player, o = !a; // 'a'ctive & 'o'pponent

    int x = a ? 0 : 6;
    int y = a ? 6 : 0;
    char *str = win ? "Wins the game\n\n" : "selects pit (1-6): ";
    printf(
        "\n"
        "----+-----player%d-----+\n"
        "%2d  |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n"
        "----+-----------------+\n"
        "%2d  |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n"
        "----+-----player%d-----+\t"

        "%d %s",
        o,  s[o], p[y+5], p[y+4], p[y+3], p[y+2], p[y+1], p[y+0], // NB: custom indexing
            s[a], p[x+0], p[x+1], p[x+2], p[x+3], p[x+4], p[x+5], a,
        a, str
    );
}

int main( void ) {
    enum { nPlayer = 2, nOne = 6, nPit = (2*nOne), nSeed = 4, nWin = 25 }; // for @M.M.

    t_Pit score[ nPlayer ] = { 0 };
    t_Pit pit[ nPit ] = { 0 };
    memset( pit, nSeed, sizeof pit );


    int actv = 0;
    for( ; score[0] < nWin && score[1] < nWin; actv = !actv ) {
        show( actv, pit, score, 0 );

        int from, to;
        if( scanf( "%d", &from ) != 1 || from < 1 || from > 6 ) {
            puts( "scanf failed" );
            return 1;
        }
        from -= 1; // 0 indexing

        if( actv == 0 ) // change to "high range" of pits?
            from += nOne;
        to = from; // for now...

        int nSow = pit[ from ];
        pit[ from ] = 0;

        while( nSow-- )
            pit[ to = (to+1)%nPit ]++;

        // condition true only while in opponent's range of pits
        for( ; to/nOne != from/nOne; to = (to+(nPit-1))%nPit ) // modulo -1
            if( pit[ to ] == 2 || pit[ to ] == 3 ) {
                score[ actv ] += pit[ to ];
                pit[ to ] = 0;
            } else break;
    }
    show( !actv, pit, score, 1 ); // have a winner (require opp. parity)

    return 0;
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: suggest using `enum` rather than `#define` for constants, so that they respect scope

Comment: @M.M Noted, thank you... The game is defined by history, and the constants are only to avoid peppering the code with _magic numbers_. `enum` is definitely an alternative the OP could explore! `:-)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!
I'm still trying to wrap my head around the variables and various functions, but the game does run as intended!! And thank you for explaining the difference between **&&** and **||**, as well as giving me a brand new approach into this challenge of mine ^^' its much more condensed and concise, and thank you so much for also explaining your process!!

Comment: @ramwen0 Thank you for posting this unusual challenge! This code works at a gross level. The Wikipedia article states "fine grain" rules that are not accounted-for here (eg: the 'from' pit is skipped-over when 'sowing' 12+ seeds.) But, it was fun to tackle the problem! Happy to explain particular aspects if you have problems. Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: @ramwen0 For fun, here's the loop that skips the 'from' pit when _sowing_: `while( nSow ) if( ( to = (to+1)%nPit ) != from ) { ++pit[ to ]; --nSow; }` That's it. Simple! `:-)`

Comment: Hey there! @Fe2O3 could you so kindly explain to me why when I try to implement the code, it doesn't run? I believe the problem is with the ```while( nSow )``` part of the code, for everything else compiles just fine.
Additionally, could you please give me a hint of how I could implement a mechanic that checks for the opponent's pits, and if empty, makes the player sow in a way that ensures seeds will go into the opponent's pits?

Comment: @ramwen0 I can't do anything with the problem described as "_it doesn't run._" The posted code here works fine for me. Re: "_ensures seeds will go into the opponent's pits_" ... The rules of sowing are clearly defined. Gameplay forces two players to strategize (and count). If you want different rules, it's simply a matter of _understanding_ the code and effecting appropriate alterations. Happy New Year...